# Contact Form 7 redirect page to specific URL based on drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My form needs to open a PDF on submit, but which PDF would be determined by one of the dropdown selections.

The dropdown is Download Document (PDF).

Upon clicking Send, I would like the page to open the PDF on submission (preferably in a new tab).

If that is not possible, simply redirecting to the appropriate PDF would suffice.

Can anyone tell me how to do this, please?

My select dropdown is like so:

```
[select* menu-121 "Spa Track Brochure" "Three Steps To 100% Control" "RFID Pod Range Datasheet" "Tray Tracker Datasheet"]
```

and the additional settings have the following code:

```
on_sent_ok: "var pdfsub = $("select[name=menu-121]").val() ; 

if(pdfsub == 'Spa Track Brochure' ){ 
   location = 'your-website1-url'; 
}

if(pdfsub == 'Three Steps To 100% Control ' ){ 
   location = 'your-website2-url'; 
} 
if(pdfsub == 'RFID Pod Range Datasheet' ){ 
   location = 'your-website3-url'; 
}
if(pdfsub == 'Tray Tracker Datasheet' ){ 
   location = 'your-website4-url'; 
}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
on_sent_ok: "var pdfsub = $("select[name = menu - 121]").val(); 

if (pdfsub == 'Spa Track Brochure') {
    window.open(
        'your-website1-url',
        '_blank'
    );
}

else if (pdfsub == 'Three Steps To 100% Control ') {
    window.open(
        'your-website1-url',
        '_blank'
    );
}
else if (pdfsub == 'RFID Pod Range Datasheet') {
    window.open(
        'your-website1-url',
        '_blank'
    );
}
else if (pdfsub == 'Tray Tracker Datasheet') {
    window.open(
        'your-website1-url',
        '_blank'
    );
}
"
```